# Ways to call an activity android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am looking for all the ways one can call another activity from an activity within the application programmatically. The one I currently know is creating a new intent, and call start intent with required activity class. Are there any other ways?

Thanks

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure it's not posssible to launch an activity without an Intent. In which specific case would you like to do that ? That's maybe the question you should ask.

Comment: What's wrong with using an Intent? It the way Android is designed, it meets any and all conceivable needs. Why do you need another way? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi there is nothing wrong, I was just trying to know whether there are other approaches or not. That is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the standard model for Activity control. `startActivity(Intent)` is a method from the Context class, which Activity subclasses.

One important distinction is between `startActivity(Intent)` and `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`. You'll use `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` if you're looking to get some result from the new Activity. The second `int` argument allows you to distinguish between multiple activities returning results (i.e., if you could potentially launch more than one sub-Activity from a given Activity). This is handled in an `onActivityResult(Intent, int, options)` method, which you can read all about [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). In general, the [Activity doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is one you should be familiar with if you're doing a lot of Android programming, because the Activity lifecycle is important and can be tricky.